# Malicious .so Library creation in CVE-2017-7494 Sambacry

Tags: exploit-development, library

I'm trying to understand the whole process behind the Sambacry exploit.
The problem is that I'm having a little problem understanding how do you create the malicious .so library to be loaded by the exploit.
I tried several techniques and they don't work. I see some precompiled examples in github but I really want to understand how to create a bind or reverse generic linux shell and output it in .so format.

I've tried msfvenom outputting to elf-so and elf to no avail.

Can you help me understand how can I create a malicious samba .so library?

PS: This question IS NOT addressed [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160443/how-does-the-cve-2017-7494-sambacry-exploit-work), I'm not asking about the exploitation process, I'm asking about the creation of the payload. Please don't tag it as a duplicate.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the CVE-2017-7494 "SambaCry" exploit work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160443/how-does-the-cve-2017-7494-sambacry-exploit-work)

Comment: If possible, can you provide the link to the exploit PoC you're trying to work with?

Comment: Yes. The exploit is located here: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/42060/

It calls the malicious library. All the exploit implementations of this CVE work the same: they call a local path where the malicious .so library is. The problem is that I don't know how to create it and don't find anything about it in the net and I want to learn how to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this open, but can you include which techniques you've tried and how exactly they didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see the code of a poc library.so and the process to compile 
https://github.com/omri9741/cve-2017-7494/blob/master/payload/